# Solitaire conundrum

Tags: probability

I've wondered about this for years and hope you might be able to figure out the answer for me.

If I played solitaire with an unshuffled pack, turned three at a time so I could only play every third card in the stack, then picked up any played cards in order from front to back and left to right and added this pile to the top of the stack, how many hands would I have to play to win?

Comment: I lack the rules of that solitare game you have in mind.

Comment: I think it's known in some areas as Klondike. You deal the cards from left to right into seven piles face down. The left pile has one card, it's neighbour two, then three. All remaining cards after dealing are the stack.

Comment: Then you turn the top card of each pile so you can see it. These cards are in play. Next you deal the stack three at a time. You can only play the face card. When you reach the end of the stack you turn it over and play three at a time again  this continues until you win or no more moves can be played.

Comment: This is too long to explain here!! Google solitaire and the pictures you find should explain it. It might just have a different name where you live.

Comment: Give us a link, Emma.

Comment: I posted that to make sure that we all talk about the same rules, this is necessary for a proper analysis - usually games come in variations.

Comment: http://m.wikihow.com/Play-Solitaire

Comment: My own additional rules are that I always play the furthest right stack if there is a choice of two or more plays.

Comment: And sorry for the dozy solitaire/patience rules explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the order of an unshuffled deck of cards, knowing the rules of the solitaire game you mean to play, and knowing the strategy by which you mean to play it (what play you will make when you are given a choice), there are no probabilistic events here. The most direct solution is probably a computer simulation, which can be run just once (until a game is won).

Your "strategy" comes into play because if you turn up your first black 5 (for example) and there are two red 4s available, you must choose which red 4 to move.

In principle, there is an exact sequence of moves (of all choices you could possibly make) that will minimize the number of games played.  Finding that sequence seems like a breadth-first search problem, again to be solved by computer.

Probabilistic methods, it seems to me, would take longer and would not necessarily yield correct answers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'm sure you've guessed but I'm no mathmatician. I did A levels in it but that's as far as I got. I just genuinely wanted to find the answer. I know some coders so I'll ask them to help. Appreciate your time everyone